# Java CSV file update

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I would like to update a .csv file containing 1 million records. I want to update in the same file without creating another file. I am using Opencsv. I don't find any way to update the .csv file. If anyone can help me out that would be great.
For clarification let's say these small .csv file:

Initial csv file:

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
12,13,14,15
```

Desired csv file:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
1,2,3,4, ,17
5,6,7,8,16,
12,13,14,15,
```

Comment: Update means what you are going to do. Please explain

Comment: I have to add new header filed and data for the field. Let's say currently I have a file with 4 headers a,b,c,d and 4 rows of data. I want to add a new header 'e' with some data.

Comment: Normally file system doesnt allow to update the file. You need to rewrite the file. Because even though you have all in one file . it will be written in multiple segments. So if you are going to change the file segments will be damaged. So you need to rewrite every thing.

Comment: Why dont you create a new file and replace with existing at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Basically - you cannot do that.

As csv does not use fixed-length records, most changes will require moving data up or down in the file. That cannot be done without completely rewriting the file.

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
...
```

changing the `8` to a `10` would require every byte from that location onwards in the whole file to be moved up one position.

To achieve the *effect* of editing the file it is usual to copy the file to a new name making the change you wish to make during the copy. You would then rename the two files so that the new one replaces the old one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to find some way and avoid rewriting the file as it contains 1 million records. Reading 1 million records and writing it back would take some time in the program that I want to avoid.

Comment: @user3387358 - If you choose a fixed-length record format you can edit it in-place using a [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). Alternatively - use a database.

Comment: I have to add a new header with some data I don't have to change existing headers.I have a file with 4 headers a,b,c,d and 4 rows of data. I want to add a new header 'e' with some data.

Comment: @user3387358 - Not sure I understand - you said you had 1 million records - now you have 4??? You could consider adding new records on the end of the file if that solves your problem.

Comment: This is just to tell you what I want I can't write here 1 million records. Please see my question for clarification. I have updated it.

Comment: @user3387358 - Understood - no you cannot do that in-place, you must create a new file. This would not be so difficult if you used a database.

Answer (score 0):

Normally file system doesnt allow to update the file. You need to rewrite the file. Because even though you have all in one file . it will be written in multiple segments. So if you are going to change the file segments will be damaged. So you need to rewrite every thing.

Comment: Okay thnx then I think there is no other way then reading and writing the whole file again.

Comment: Ya definitely there is no way.